# Gamma Function Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Hi is it fair to write $$\Gamma(1+ix)=ix\Gamma(ix) $$
and then to say that $\Gamma(ix)=\exp(i\arg(\Gamma(x)))$. If not can anyone explain what $\arg(\Gamma(x))$ is defined as please, I always get confused with arguments and things.

Comment: $\arg(z) = \Im(\log(z))$. Note that $\exp(i \arg(\Gamma(x)))$ is the complex number of unit magnitude, while $|\Gamma(i x)|$ is generically not equal to 1.

Comment: is this correct if it is $i\Gamma(ix)-\exp(i\arg(\Gamma(ix)))$? if no how can one get this argument inside an exponentail?